# smarty - two or more inequality conditions in one bracket?

Tags: smarty

This is my code in smarty:

```
{if $cat!="1_5"} do something {/if}
```

If I add additional condition with `or`:

```
{if $cat!="1_5" or $cat!="2_30"} do something {/if}
```

Then it doesn't work in proper way. Why? Is this possible to use in one brackets two or more inequality conditions?

Comment: Yes, it sure is possible to put multiple conditions in an `if`. What exactly do you mean with `code stops working`? Is there nothing being outputted? Are you sure the conditions return true? I guess it rather should be `if $cat!="1_5" and $cat!="2_30"`

Comment: If I have `{if $cat!="1_5"} do something {/if}` then "do something" doesn't shows only when `$cat=="1_5"` but when I have additional condition then "do something" I can see even when `$cat=="1_5"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright, so we have the categories **1_5** and **2_30**

let's see what happens in your if-condition when `$cat="2_30"`

```
$cat!="1_5"     $cat!="2_30"                    $cat!="1_5"    $cat!="2_30"
       |         |                                    |         |
     TRUE      FALSE                                TRUE      FALSE
        \       /                                      \       /
         \     /                   but:                 \     /
          \   /                                          \   /
            OR                                             AND
            |                                               |
          TRUE                                            FALSE
     //do something                                //don't do something
```

So, you get the idea :) You have to use `AND` instead of `OR`:

```
{if $cat!="1_5" and $cat!="2_30"} do something {/if}
```

Comment: Amazing, this way works! I need to add `and` istead of `or`. Thank you.