# What is the meaning of var = var || {}

Tags: javascript

I have recently downloaded a code from web and trying to understand it. I have found one line right above the js file which can be seen as below:

```
var Liip = Liip || {};
```

Can someone explain to me what is this line doing?

Comment: Initializing local variable Liip as global (or passed onto function) variable Liip, or, if such global/passed variable doesnt exist, an empty object. Its essentially a default setting.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553314/what-does-javascript-somevalue-mean http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851404/what-does-options-options-mean-in-javascript

Answer (score 3):

It means that `Liip` will either hold `Liip` and if it is not defined, then it will be an empty object `{}`

Answer (score 1):

This is a common idiom used to assign default values to things that haven't been specified.

In this instances, it makes `Liip` default to an empty object.

The main pitfall is that it is based on the notion of ["truthiness"](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/), and would replace things like the number zero with the default.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain what they think is wrong with the answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If `Liip` is `undefined` it will assign `{}`.

It can be expressed also as:

```
Liip = Liip? Liip: {};
```

OR

```
if (Liip){
    Liip = Liip;
}
else {
    Liip = {};
}
```

OR

```
if (typeof(Liip) === 'undefined'){
    Liip = {};
}
else {
    Liip = Liip;
}
```

---

For reference:
It's equivalent to C#:

```
int? nullableInt = getNumber();
int Liip = nullableInt?? 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a trick of using lazy evaluation

if you type something like:

`if (true || false)`

Then the interpreter doesn't look at `false` at all as this doesn't have any impact to the result. That's because `||` (or) will return `true` IF ANY of the components is true and when we know that the first part evaluates to `true`, then we can be sure that the whole sentence evaluates to `true` (in javacript it's even more simplified by simply returning this part)

so

`true || anything || something`

always return `true`

and if the first part evaluates to `false`, then the interpreter looks at the next part consequently and returns `anything` or `something` if `anything` is false as well.

this way

`0 || 0 || 2` returns `2`

`0 || 3 || 3` returns `3`

and:

`undefined || {}` returns `{}`

`true || {}` returns `true`

You can also use `&&` to make interpreter look at the next part if the first part is NOT equal to false

`true && 2` returns `2`

`false && 2` returns `false`

that's because `&&` (AND) returns `true` if all of the components evaluates to `true`. So there's no need to look at `2` if the first part is `false`.